# How many different sets of $6$ different numbers can we construct from $11, 13, 18, 19, 19, 20, 23, 25$?

Tags: combinatorics

Shouldn't be repeated in any case; if the numbers appeared is exactly the same as another but different orders, that doesn't count as a new set. For example: $11,13,18,19,19,20$ is the same as $13, 18, 19,11,19,20$.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have 19 twice, you can just consider 11, 13, 18, 19, 20, 23 and 25. There are 7 numbers here, so to create a set of 6 you just omit one. Since there are 7 distinct numbers, there are 7 ways of making a set of 6 by omitting a different one each time.